# Repeating Microsoft Word VBA until no search results found

Tags: vba, ms-word

I've created a MS Word macro that searches for certain text (indicated by markup codes), cuts the text and inserts it into a new footnote, and then deletes the markup codes from the footnote.  Now I want the macro to repeat until it doesn't find any more markup codes in the text.
Here's the macro below

```
Sub SearchFN()

'find a footnote
Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
With Selection.Find
    .Text = "&&FB:*&&FE"
    .Replacement.Text = ""
    .Forward = True
    .Wrap = wdFindContinue
    .Format = False
    .MatchCase = False
    .MatchWholeWord = False
    .MatchKashida = False
    .MatchDiacritics = False
    .MatchAlefHamza = False
    .MatchControl = False
    .MatchByte = False
    .MatchAllWordForms = False
    .MatchSoundsLike = False
    .MatchFuzzy = False
    .MatchWildcards = True
End With
Selection.Find.Execute

'cut the footnote from the text
Selection.Cut

'create a proper Word footnote
With Selection
    With .FootnoteOptions
        .Location = wdBottomOfPage
        .NumberingRule = wdRestartContinuous
        .StartingNumber = 1
        .NumberStyle = wdNoteNumberStyleArabic
    End With
    .Footnotes.Add Range:=Selection.Range, Reference:=""
End With

'now paste the text into the footnote
Selection.Paste

'go to the beginning of the newly created footnote
'and find/delete the code for the start of the note (&&FB:)
    Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
Selection.Find.Replacement.ClearFormatting
With Selection.Find
    .Text = "&&FB:"
    .Replacement.Text = ""
    .Forward = False
    .Wrap = wdFindContinue
    .Format = False
    .MatchCase = False
    .MatchWholeWord = False
    .MatchKashida = False
    .MatchDiacritics = False
    .MatchAlefHamza = False
    .MatchControl = False
    .MatchByte = False
    .MatchAllWordForms = False
    .MatchSoundsLike = False
    .MatchFuzzy = False
    .MatchWildcards = True
End With
Selection.Find.Execute
With Selection
    If .Find.Forward = True Then
        .Collapse Direction:=wdCollapseStart
    Else
        .Collapse Direction:=wdCollapseEnd
    End If
    .Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceOne
    If .Find.Forward = True Then
        .Collapse Direction:=wdCollapseEnd
    Else
        .Collapse Direction:=wdCollapseStart
    End If
    .Find.Execute
End With

'do same for ending code (&&FE)
With Selection.Find
    .Text = "&&FE"
    .Replacement.Text = ""
    .Forward = True
    .Wrap = wdFindContinue
    .Format = False
    .MatchCase = False
    .MatchWholeWord = False
    .MatchKashida = False
    .MatchDiacritics = False
    .MatchAlefHamza = False
    .MatchControl = False
    .MatchByte = False
    .MatchAllWordForms = False
    .MatchSoundsLike = False
    .MatchFuzzy = False
    .MatchWildcards = True
End With
Selection.Find.Execute
With Selection
    If .Find.Forward = True Then
        .Collapse Direction:=wdCollapseStart
    Else
        .Collapse Direction:=wdCollapseEnd
    End If
    .Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceOne
    If .Find.Forward = True Then
        .Collapse Direction:=wdCollapseEnd
    Else
        .Collapse Direction:=wdCollapseStart
    End If
    .Find.Execute
End With

Selection.HomeKey Unit:=wdStory
'now repeat--but how??    

End Sub
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Good question this one, you can loop through the whole document using the `Selection.Find.Found` result.

What you do is start a search and if you find a result go into a loop only while the `Selection.Find.Found` result is true.  Once you've got through these, you're done.  The following code should do the trick nicely for you.

```
Sub SearchFN()
    Dim iCount As Integer

    'Always start at the top of the document
    Selection.HomeKey Unit:=wdStory

    'find a footnote to kick it off
    With Selection.Find
        .ClearFormatting
        .Text = "&&FB:*&&FE"
        .Replacement.Text = ""
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindContinue
        .Format = False
        .MatchCase = False
        .MatchWholeWord = False
        .MatchKashida = False
        .MatchDiacritics = False
        .MatchAlefHamza = False
        .MatchControl = False
        .MatchByte = False
        .MatchAllWordForms = False
        .MatchSoundsLike = False
        .MatchFuzzy = False
        .MatchWildcards = True
        .Execute
    End With

    'If we find one then we can set off a loop to keep checking
    'I always put a counter in to avoid endless loops for one reason or another
    Do While Selection.Find.Found = True And iCount < 1000
        iCount = iCount + 1

        'Jump back to the start of the document.  Since you remove the
        'footnote place holder this won't pick up old results
        Selection.HomeKey Unit:=wdStory
        Selection.Find.Execute

        'On the last loop you'll not find a result so check here
        If Selection.Find.Found Then

            ''==================================
            '' Do your footnote magic here
            ''==================================

            'Reset the find parameters
            With Selection.Find
                .ClearFormatting
                .Text = "&&FB:*&&FE"
                .Replacement.Text = ""
                .Forward = True
                .Wrap = wdFindContinue
                .Format = False
                .MatchCase = False
                .MatchWholeWord = False
                .MatchKashida = False
                .MatchDiacritics = False
                .MatchAlefHamza = False
                .MatchControl = False
                .MatchByte = False
                .MatchAllWordForms = False
                .MatchSoundsLike = False
                .MatchFuzzy = False
                .MatchWildcards = True
            End With
        End If
    Loop
End Sub
```

Answer (score 3):

This can be done without using `Do while`(lots of extra lines, and space/time wastage), It could be as simple as follows:

```
Sub SearchFN()

    'Start from The Top
    Selection.HomeKey Unit:=wdStory

    'Find the first search to start the loop
    Do
    With Selection.Find
        .ClearFormatting
        .Replacement.ClearFormatting
        .Text = "&&FB:*&&FE"
        .Replacement.Text = ""
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindstop
        .Format = False
        .MatchCase = False
        .MatchWholeWord = False
        .MatchKashida = False
        .MatchDiacritics = False
        .MatchAlefHamza = False
        .MatchControl = False
        .MatchByte = False
        .MatchAllWordForms = False
        .MatchSoundsLike = False
        .MatchFuzzy = False
        .MatchWildcards = True
        .Execute
    End With

    'If we found the result then loop started
    If Selection.Find.Found Then

            '' Do your work here
            ' Always end your work after the first found result
            ' else it will be endless loop

    Else
    'If we do not found any then it will exit the loop
    Exit Do
    End If
    Loop

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to do this is to make the function recursive (the function recalls itself). Add this one line to the bottom of your sub or function:

```
If (Selection.Find.Found = True) then call SearchFN
```

Comment: Is syntactically simple and clean but the trade-off is redundant re-execution of all of the overhead code that sets the various Find options.  On modern systems, execution time is rarely an issue but this technique is an example of what I call "pretty on the outside; ugly on the inside."  Sometimes that's the best choice, but it does rankle my inner purist.