# Performing an action using VBA

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have a block of text in a MS word file like below:

```
[[ul]]
•   For the near term, all Cendoc content will be ingested into the NextBook_Cendoc_June2011 database. 
•   You must navigate to and open this database before you can ingest Cendoc XML. 
•   You can locate this database for the first time by selecting the DATABASE option from the blue navigation bar at the top of the screen. Select the “Browse all database/choose a database” option. Select the “NextBook_Cendoc_June2011” link from the menu. 
[[/ul]]
```

And I need an output as below using VBA

```
<list identifier="" list-style="Unordered">
<item identifier=""""><para identifier="">For the near term, all Cendoc content will be ingested into the NextBook_Cendoc_June2011 database.</para></item>
<item identifier=""""><para identifier="">You must navigate to and open this database before you can ingest Cendoc XML.</para></item>
<item identifier=""""><para identifier="">You can locate this database for the first time by selecting the DATABASE option from the blue navigation bar at the top of the screen. Select the “Browse all database/choose a database” option. Select the “NextBook_Cendoc_June2011” link from the menu.</para></item>
</list>
```

What should I do?

Comment: Search and replace? You could record the search and replace action as a VBA macro and modify it so you can use it again.

Comment: Not by search and replace. It's not happening by so.

Comment: What do you mean by _not happening_? Doesn't a search for `[[ul]]` and replace it with `<list identifier="" list-style="Unordered">` work, or is it that you don't want to do it that way?

Comment: Dear Sir, I want to perform the action block wise not individually. Since the document have more such lists.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I did what I suggested and recorded a search and replace macro for you, and this is what I came up with.

```
Option Explicit

Sub SearchAndReplace()

    Selection.HomeKey Unit:=wdStory

    With Selection.Find
        .Text = "[[ul]]"
        .Replacement.Text = "<list identifier="""" list-style=""Unordered"">"
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindContinue
        .Format = False
        .MatchCase = False
        .MatchWholeWord = False
        .MatchWildcards = False
        .MatchSoundsLike = False
        .MatchAllWordForms = False
    End With
    Selection.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll


    With Selection.Find
        .Text = "•   "
        .Replacement.Text = _
            "<item identifier=""""""""><para identifier="""">"
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindContinue
        .Format = False
        .MatchCase = False
        .MatchWholeWord = False
        .MatchWildcards = False
        .MatchSoundsLike = False
        .MatchAllWordForms = False
    End With
    Selection.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll


    With Selection.Find
        .Text = "[[/ul]]"
        .Replacement.Text = "</list>"
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindAsk
        .Format = False
        .MatchCase = False
        .MatchWholeWord = False
        .MatchWildcards = False
        .MatchSoundsLike = False
        .MatchAllWordForms = False
    End With
    Selection.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll

End Sub
```

Comment: Also, see the following answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13465709/repeating-ms-word-macro-until-no-search-results-found/14309412#14309412