# Word 2007 VBA - Making some text BOLD & other ITALIC

Tags: vba, formatting, ms-word

I have the following code that selects data from an Excel Cell & replaces a specific piece of text in my Word document (for purposes of this question, the Excel Cell has been replaced by a plain text string).

The data ": goes to " is constant, then the data "aaa bbb" can be anything until we reach the " of " which is also constant. Then the data after the " of ", "ccc ddd eee" can be anything until it hits the " - " which is also constant.

Is it possible to make the "aaa bbb" data **BOLD** & UPPER CASE, whilst making the "ccc ddd eee" data into *ITALICS* ?

": goes to **AAA BBB** of *ccc ddd eee* - "

```
Selection.HomeKey Unit:=wdStory
Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
Selection.Find.Replacement.ClearFormatting
With Selection.Find
    .Text = "MOTMDIV1"
    .Replacement.Text = ": goes to aaa bbb of ccc ddd eee - "
    .Forward = True
    .Wrap = wdFindContinue
    .Format = False
    .MatchCase = True
    .MatchWholeWord = False
    .MatchWildcards = False
    .MatchSoundsLike = False
    .MatchAllWordForms = False
End With

Selection.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you change your Find and Replace to a single Find and Replace from All, Word will highlight the replaced text allowing you to alter the properties of the replaced range.  I've modified your code to highlight this:

```
Sub ReplaceAndFormat()
   Dim sConst1 As String, sConst2 As String, sReplaceMent As String
   Dim rRange As Range, rFormat As Range

    'Set your constants.  This is where you can read in from Excel or whereever
   sConst1 = "aaa bbb"
    sConst2 = "ccc ddd eee"

    'Build the replacement string
    sReplaceMent = ": goes to " & sConst1 & " of " & sConst2 & " - "

    'Your replacement code
    Selection.HomeKey Unit:=wdStory
    Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
    Selection.Find.Replacement.ClearFormatting
    With Selection.Find
       .Text = "MOTMDIV1"
        .Replacement.Text = sReplaceMent
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindContinue
        .Format = False
        .MatchCase = True
        .MatchWholeWord = False
        .MatchWildcards = False
        .MatchSoundsLike = False
        .MatchAllWordForms = False
        .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceOne

       'If we replace one by one Word will select the range after it finds it
        If .Found Then
            'After you've done the replacement, set it to a range so you can format
            Set rRange = Selection.Range

           'We know the length of all the strings so we can set the range of the "aaa bbb" etc etc 
           Set rFormat = ActiveDocument.Range(rRange.Start + 10, rRange.Start + 10 + VBA.Len(sConst1))
           'Set the formats for the first part
           rFormat.Font.Bold = True
           rFormat.Font.AllCaps = True

           'Repeat for the second part
           Set rFormat = ActiveDocument.Range(rRange.Start + 14 + VBA.Len(sConst1), rRange.Start + 14 + VBA.Len(sConst1) + VBA.Len(sConst2))
           rFormat.Font.Italic = True
       End If
   End With
End Sub
```

Note: If you want to Find and Replace all instantences of your search text then you'll have to loop through the document like this: [Repeating Microsoft Word VBA until no search results found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13465709/repeating-ms-word-macro-until-no-search-results-found/14309412#14309412)

Comment: I will have a look & try this over the weekend, I can't now as I've had a few beers, but thanks CuberChase ...

Comment: No worries mate. You know what they say here in Australia. "If you drink and code you're a bloody idiot". Oh, no wait, that's about driving.

Comment: Sorry I haven't got back to you, have been stuck on a different part of the code ... haven't forgotten this !!! And it's a good job drinking & coding isn't frowned upon, I'd never get anything done ;-) !!!

Comment: Not a problem. It should be straight forward so hopefully you can celebrate with a beer :)

Comment: Just looking at it now, it does work, yes, thanks, but from what I can see & understand it assumes that the original input is fixed, which it isn't ... BUT, I can work around that by breaking it up & assigning it to variables before I hit your code, so thank you, I should be able to do exactly what I want with this :-)

Comment: Thats great!  Yeah, all you need to do is turn it into a function by moving the `sConst1` and `sConst2` to be input variables.