# Microsoft Word macro for formatting selected text, such as italics for all instances of e.g

Tags: vba, ms-word

this is my first question,
I have to go over a large number of documents and make sure that several formatting issues are correct. An example of such an issue would be to make sure that all periods, ".", are not bold, italics, underline, etc. Another example would be to make sure that all "etc." are in italics.

I have a list of the needed formatting issues.

Instead of going over each document and using the find/replace function I would rather write a macro that I can apply to each document.

I have no experience with VBA. I do on the other hand, have some experience with programming in C sharp and C in general.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

BTW, I'm not asking for a complete program, rather a sample from which I can learn and continue with my own.

Comment: Macro recorder will produce all the required code for you when you'll record all such changes while performing them manually.

Comment: Have a look at these two answers: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13465709/repeating-ms-word-macro-until-no-search-results-found/14309412#14309412 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14773971/word-2007-vba-making-some-text-bold-other-italic/14781570#14781570

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple options:

1.Under the Developer tab in Word, you can hit the "Record Macro" button and do a find and replace multiple times while recording the macro using the ctrl + H shortcut.

2.Have multiple smaller macros setup (such as the two below) hit the "Record Macro" and run them in the order that you want.

```
Sub ItalicizeEct()
  Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
  Selection.Find.Replacement.ClearFormatting
  Selection.Find.Replacement.Font.Italic = True
  With Selection.Find
    .Text = "ect."
    .Replacement.Text = ""
    .Forward = True
    .Wrap = wdFindContinue
    .Format = True
    .MatchCase = False
    .MatchWholeWord = False
    .MatchWildcards = False
    .MatchSoundsLike = False
    .MatchAllWordForms = False
  End With
  Selection.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
End Sub

Sub RemoveBoldPeriods()
  Dim PunctAllRng As Word.Range
  Set PunctAllRng = ActiveDocument.Range
  With PunctAllRng.Find
  .Format = True
  .Text = "."
  .Font.Bold = True
  .Replacement.Text = "."
  .Replacement.Font.Bold = False
  .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
End With
End Sub
```

3.Or simply write a large macro that will go through all the editing processes you need