# How to Find and change words to Italic in Office Interop Word

Tags: c#, office-interop

I need to Find all occurrences of specific words and make them italic.
I can find the first occurence of each word very easily, but with the while loop I cant, it creates an inifite loop, as though setting the start range doesn't update the range... Maybe I am being very silly but here is my logic:

Get first occurrence, 
make Italic,

set start range to next char after first occurrence,

repeat until there are no more occurrences...

```
appWord = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application();
wordDocument = appWord.Documents.Open("pathToFile", Type.Missing, false);
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Range rng = wordDocument.Range();

string[] latinTerms = new []{"inter alia","invicta" };
for (int i = 0; i < latinTerms.Length; i++)
{
        while (rng.Text.IndexOf(latinTerms[i]) != -1)
        {
            int start = rng.Text.IndexOf(latinTerms[i]);
            int end = start + latinTerms[i].Length;

            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Range tmpRange = wordDocument.Range(start, end);
            tmpRange.Select();
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Selection currSel = appWord.Selection;
            currSel.ItalicRun();
            rng.Start = end + 1;
        }
}
```

I use Find.Execute to replace chars and strings, that works great, but I haven't found a way to change chars and strings to italic...

Comment: Do you need to use Office Interop? An alternative technique could be to save the file as a .rtf file, and then read it with your C# program and do find-and-replace on the RTF data using simple string processing. Then save the result as .rtf and read that back into Word.

Comment: It's a "trivial" part of a much larger document parsing app so that could have been a last resort, luckily I have found the solution, thank you anyways for your time and input, Appreciate it! +1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
private void FindAndItalicize(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application doc, object findText)
    {
        var rng = doc.Selection.Range;

        while(rng.Find.Execute(findText))
        {
            rng.Font.Italic = 1;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Perfect! I was having issues setting my fonts till I found this post.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you are interested in the [Italic](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff836352.aspx) property of the Font class.

See [Word 2007 VBA - Making some text BOLD & other ITALIC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14773971/word-2007-vba-making-some-text-bold-other-italic) for a sample code.

Comment: +1 Although it didn't give me the answer, you definitely showed me how it was being resolved similarly in VBA, so I got searching and playing around until I got it to work in a whooping 3 lines... Thank you Eugene