# Find.Execute with confirmation dialog

Tags: vba, replace, ms-word

I'm writing a macro in Visual Basic (ugh, I know) to parse documents in Microsoft Word. This is the workflow I'm trying to achieve:

- Search for a string in the document (equivalent to `Edit > Find > Find...`).
- Ask the user if he or she wants to replace the matching string with another string (equivalent to `Edit > Find > Replace... > Replace`, but with a confirmation dialog before performing the replacement).
- If yes, do the replacement. If not, go to the next match.

I can do the finding and replacing with the [`Find.Execute` method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff193977(v=office.14).aspx):

```
Set myRange = ActiveDocument.Content 
myRange.Find.Execute FindText:="hi", _ 
    ReplaceWith:="hello", Replace:=wdReplaceAll
```

But I'm not sure how to prompt the user before performing the replacement.

Comment: When a user performs a find/replace using the UI, the only confirmation that he would receive is *after* the replace has been done (assuming that the text to find was found). This can be toggled using the `Application.DisplayAlerts` property. If you want to show a dialog box *before* replacing text, you need to check if anything was find and loop through the results like this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14309412/1710577

Comment: Also, do you want a confirmation for each *instance* of a string of text that is found on the document OR for each different strings of text that you find?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can prompt with a message box, then test the return value and perform the replacement based on that:

```
Private Sub PromptForReplace()

    Dim myRange As Range

    Set myRange = ActiveDocument.Content
    myRange.Find.ClearFormatting
    myRange.Find.MatchWildcards = True

    Dim cached As Long
    cached = myRange.End
    Do While myRange.Find.Execute("hi")
        myRange.Select
        If MsgBox("Replace " & myRange.Find.Text & "?", vbYesNo) = vbYes Then
            myRange.Text = "hello"
        End If
        myRange.Start = myRange.Start + Len(myRange.Find.Text)
        myRange.End = cached
    Loop

End Sub
```

Comment: In `MsgBox()`, is it possible to print the matched text (in this case, "hi")?

Comment: Thanks. I didn't phrase it well, but what I meant to ask was: how do I access the matched text so that I can include it in the prompt? For instance: `MsgBox('Replace with ' + match + '?', vbYesNo)`.

Comment: @JoeMornin - I'm not sure I follow - the matched text will always be what you search for unless you're using wildcards. Do you need to add search more parameters like only matching words and not substrings? The easiest way would be to just select the match in the document.

Comment: Yep, I'll be using wildcards. Selecting the match in the document would be fine, too.