# Why is range.find searching like this?

Tags: vba, ms-word

I am trying to search for occurrences of a particular string in a Word document.
The code should search only after the Table of Contents.
My completed code is below:

```
Private Sub cmdFindNextAbbr_Click()

    Dim myRange As range

    'CREATING DICTONARY for Selected Items
    If firstClickAbr = True Then

        txtNew = ""

        abSelIndex = 0
        Set abSel = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
        Set abSelFirstStart = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")

        firstClickAbr = False
        iAbbr = 0
        For x = 0 To lstAbbreviations.ListCount - 1
            If lstAbbreviations.Selected(x) = True Then
                If Not abSel.Exists(lstAbbreviations.List(x, 1)) Then
                    abSel.Add lstAbbreviations.List(x, 0), lstAbbreviations.List(x, 1)
                    abSelFirstStart.Add lstAbbreviations.List(x, 0), lstAbbreviations.List(x, 5)
                End If
            End If
        Next x
    End If

    Dim Word, findText As String
    Dim chkAbbrLast, fsCountExt, firstOccEnd As Integer

    Do While abSelIndex < abSel.count
        chkAbbrLast = 0

        Set myRange = ActiveDocument.Content

        If txtNew <> abSel.keys()(abSelIndex) Then
            fnCountAbr = 0
            locInteger = abbrTableEnd
        End If

        firstOccEnd = abSelFirstStart.items()(abSelIndex) + Len(abSel.items()(abSelIndex) & " (" & abSel.keys()(abSelIndex) & ")")
        fnCountAbr = fnCountAbr + 1
        Word = abSel.keys()(abSelIndex)

        'initially search for full text
        findText = abSel.items()(abSelIndex)

        myRange.Start = locInteger
        myRange.Find.ClearFormatting
        Do While myRange.Find.Execute( _
                    findText:=findText, _
                    MatchCase:=False, _
                    MatchWholeWord:=True, _
                    Wrap:=wdFindStop, _
                    Forward:=True _
                    )

            If Left(myRange.Style, 7) <> "Heading" Then
                If abSelFirstStart.items()(abSelIndex) <> myRange.Start Then 'ignore the first occurrence

                    locInteger = myRange.End
                    tCount = tCount + 1

                    'check for full term and abbreviation
                    fsCountExt = Len(abSel.items()(abSelIndex) & "s (" & abSel.keys()(abSelIndex) & "s)")
                    myRange.End = myRange.Start + fsCountExt

                    If InStr(UCase(myRange.Text), UCase(abSel.items()(abSelIndex) & "s (" & abSel.keys()(abSelIndex) & "s)")) > 0 Then
                        txtNew = abSel.keys()(abSelIndex) & "s"
                        myRange.Select
                        Exit Sub
                    Else
                        fsCountExt = Len(abSel.items()(abSelIndex) & " (" & abSel.keys()(abSelIndex) & ")")
                        myRange.End = myRange.Start + fsCountExt
                    End If

                    If InStr(UCase(myRange.Text), UCase(abSel.items()(abSelIndex) & " (" & abSel.keys()(abSelIndex) & ")")) > 0 Then
                        txtNew = abSel.keys()(abSelIndex)
                        myRange.Select
                        Exit Sub
                    End If

                    'check for full term only
                    fsCountExt = Len(abSel.items()(abSelIndex) & "s (" & abSel.keys()(abSelIndex) & "s)")
                    myRange.End = myRange.Start + fsCountExt

                    If InStr(UCase(myRange.Text), UCase(abSel.items()(abSelIndex) & "s")) > 0 Then
                        txtNew = abSel.keys()(abSelIndex) & "s"
                        myRange.Select
                        Exit Sub
                    Else
                        fsCountExt = Len(abSel.items()(abSelIndex))
                        myRange.End = myRange.Start + fsCountExt
                    End If

                    If InStr(UCase(myRange.Text), UCase(abSel.items()(abSelIndex))) > 0 Then
                        txtNew = abSel.keys()(abSelIndex)
                        myRange.Select
                        Exit Sub
                    End If
                End If
            End If
                chkAbbrLast = chkAbbrLast + 1     ' check to prevent infinite loop
            myRange.End = ActiveDocument.Content.End
            If chkAbbrLast > 2 Then
                Exit Do
            End If
        Loop

        'now search for abbreviation
        findText = abSel.keys()(abSelIndex)
        chkAbbrLast = 0
        myRange.Start = locInteger
        myRange.Find.ClearFormatting
        Do While myRange.Find.Execute( _
                    findText:=findText, _
                    MatchCase:=True, _
                    MatchWholeWord:=True _
                    )

            If Left(myRange.Style, 7) <> "Heading" And myRange.Start > firstOccEnd Then

                If abbIgnoreList.contains(myRange.Start) Then ' skip if match is in ignore list
                    If abSelIndex = abSel.count - 1 Then
                        chkAbbrLast = chkAbbrLast + 1   ' check to prevent infinite loop
                    End If
                    locInteger = myRange.End
                Else
                    locInteger = myRange.End
                    tCount = tCount + 1

                    fsCountExt = Len(abSel.keys()(abSelIndex) & "s")
                    myRange.End = myRange.Start + fsCountExt

                    If InStr(UCase(myRange.Text), UCase(abSel.keys()(abSelIndex) & "s")) > 0 Then
                        txtNew = abSel.keys()(abSelIndex) & "s"
                        myRange.Select
                        Exit Sub
                    Else
                        fsCountExt = Len(abSel.keys()(abSelIndex))
                        myRange.End = myRange.Start + fsCountExt
                    End If

                    If InStr(UCase(myRange.Text), UCase(abSel.keys()(abSelIndex))) > 0 Then
                        txtNew = abSel.keys()(abSelIndex)
                        myRange.Select
                        Exit Sub
                    End If
                End If

            End If
                chkAbbrLast = chkAbbrLast + 1     ' check to prevent infinite loop
            If chkAbbrLast > 2 Then
                Exit Do
            End If
            myRange.End = ActiveDocument.Content.End

        Loop

        'loop to next/first item
        If abSelIndex <= abSel.count - 1 Then
            abSelIndex = abSelIndex + 1
        Else
            abSelIndex = 0 ' start again at beginning
        End If
    Loop

    MsgBox "No further occurrences found"
End Sub
```

`ToCEnd` is 4085.

I am able to find the first result. When I click on a find next button, which calls the same method, I have the below values:

```
myRange.Start : 18046
myRange.End : 21467
```

However, after `.Find.Execute`, I have the below values:

```
myRange.Start : 18022
myRange.End : 18046
```

Why does the found text end at the start point I had defined earlier?
The difference between `Start` and `End` is the length of my string, 24

EDIT:
I have added the complete code.

What I am doing in the code is finding the text that the user may replace.
The replace is triggered from another button.

In the `Find Next` button event, I validate a result, store the end of the range to a variable and exit the sub.
On the next click, I am trying to search from the stored location onward.

I updated my code to be like the one at [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29736847/find-execute-with-confirmation-dialog), still I have the same behavior.

Comment: Show us the entire code that has to do with Find - an [mvce]. We can't do any analysis on what's provided. Also, include what `ToCEnd` is.

Comment: If you where performing a  Replace All then you wouldn't use a Do While. You say that you press a Next button ...if that executes the same code that you've kind of implied here, then depending on what exactly you replaced, the routine will only find what it partially replaced in the previous Find/Replace. If you truly need to iterate thru the document, then that is inconsistent with having to manually click next. @CindyMeister is correct, you need to properly complete your question by supplying the full code and I would add ... a fuller explanation of what you are attempting to do.

Comment: Picking up from your second question: Please edit *this* question with the information about the problem being when the "find" lands in a table. That is a special case. Please "ping" when you have done so.

Comment: @CindyMeister I have currently modified my UI and code quite a bit, and using Selection.Find, which is when 'find' lands in a table.

Comment: Thing is, Selection.Find is not usually a good idea; Range.Find is usually preferable. Anyway, do *not* rely on the Start and End numbers - those can change. If you want to come back to a position set a (temporary) bookmark at that position.

Answer (score 1):

You apparently want to loop through the found instances. For that you could use code like:

```
Sub Demo()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim i As Long
With ActiveDocument.Range
  With .Find
    .ClearFormatting
    .Replacement.ClearFormatting
    .Text = InputBox("What is the Text to Find")
    .Replacement.Text = ""
    .Forward = True
    .Wrap = wdFindStop
    .Format = False
    .MatchCase = False
    .MatchWholeWord = False
    .MatchWildcards = False
    .MatchSoundsLike = False
    .MatchAllWordForms = False
    .Execute
  End With
  Do While .Find.Found
    i = i + 1
    'insert code to do something with whatever's been found here
    .Collapse wdCollapseEnd
    .Find.Execute
  Loop
End With
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
MsgBox i & " instances found."
End Sub
```

Comment: I want to find the next occurrence of an abbreviation or its corresponding full term. Looping through the found instances does not work for me

Comment: Au contraire, looping through the found instances does return the next occurrence of an abbreviation or its corresponding full term, depending on which of these you're searching for. In fact, it finds and resets the range to each & every 'next' instance as it encounters it.