# How to find a word in a document from the current selection onwards

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have an extract of code that searches for a word in a document from the current selection to the end. The intention of this is so the next time it's run it will find the next instance and so on.

It works fine until it finds a word within a table, at which point it won't find anything after that entry. I need to be able to find words in tables as well as text. It also runs as a function in a userform (running modeless), waiting for user input then providing different words, looping and performing actions depending on user input. So I don't believe I can run my other code within the find section (although I'm happy to be corrected).

```
Sub test1()

Dim list() As String
Dim wrd As String
Dim mrk As Integer

wrd = "ABC" 'Get next word from list

'set range to search as from current selection (previously found) to end of document
Dim DocRng
Set DocRng = ActiveDocument.Range(Start:=Selection.End, End:=ActiveDocument.Content.End)

mrk = Selection.End 'Mark end of previously found instance (current selection)

With DocRng.Find 'Find next instance of word and select it
     .Text = wrd
     .MatchCase = True
     .Forward = True
     .Execute
     DocRng.Select
End With

If Selection.End = mrk Then 'If selection hasn't changed inform user and go to start of document
    MsgBox ("Reached end of document.")
    Selection.GoTo What:=wdGoToLine, Which:=wdGoToAbsolute, Count:=0
End If

tmp = Selection.Text 'Save currently selected text

End Sub
```

How do I get it to find entries past the table?

Comment: The Answer in this discussion should help. Read the description about using Find on cell-by-cell basis in the table. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51925805/vba-how-to-start-a-selection-halfway-through-the-text-in-a-table/51932924#51932924

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By searching the whole document (or specified range) and storing the locations of each instance in an array, you can then compare those locations to the current selection and select the instance after the current selection.

```
Function search()

Dim list() As String
Dim Wrd As String
Dim k As Integer
Dim Nfound As Boolean

Dim Def As String
Dim location() As String

'Search document and get locations of each instance of a word

Wrd = "ABC" 'Get next word from list
Def = "Alphabet"
k = 1

Dim DocRng
Set DocRng = ActiveDocument.Content 'search whole document

With DocRng.find
     .Text = Wrd
     .MatchCase = True

    Do While .Execute 'For each entry found, store start and end to array
        ReDim Preserve location(2, k)
        location(1, k) = DocRng.Start
        location(2, k) = DocRng.End
        k = k + 1
    Loop

End With

'Compare the found locations against the current selection and select the first instance after current selection

Nfound = True 'Set as not found until it is found

    j = Selection.End 'mark current cursor location

    For k = 1 To UBound(location, 2)
        If location(1, k) > j + Len(Def) Then '+ Len(Def) accounts for changes to text
            ActiveDocument.Range(Start:=location(1, k), End:=location(2, k)).Select
            Nfound = False
            Exit For
        End If
    Next

    If Nfound Then 'if not found got to first instance found
        k = 1
        ActiveDocument.Range(Start:=location(1, k), End:=location(2, k)).Select
    End If

End Function
```

Answer (score 1):

You can run other code within a Find/Replace loop, using code like:

```
Sub Demo()
With ActiveDocument.Range
  With .Find
    .ClearFormatting
    .Replacement.ClearFormatting
    .Text = InputBox("What is the Text to Find")
    .Replacement.Text = ""
    .Forward = True
    .Wrap = wdFindStop
    .Format = False
    .MatchCase = True
    .MatchWholeWord = True
    .MatchWildcards = False
    .MatchSoundsLike = False
    .MatchAllWordForms = False
    .Execute
  End With
  Do While .Find.Found
    .Select
    Select Case MsgBox("Replace this one?", vbYesNoCancel)
      Case vbCancel: Exit Sub
      Case vbYes: .Text = InputBox("Replacement text")
      Case Else
    End Select
    .Collapse wdCollapseEnd
    .Find.Execute
  Loop
End With
End Sub
```

Such code is unaffected by tables.

Comment: Thanks, but the userform I'm currently using has 5 buttons (may end up with more), and I'm also running it modeless to let the user manually edit it in place. Which as far as I know can't be done with a message box.

Comment: @Kagekiba Did you try it? In any event, you could modify the code so all the inputs & responses are done from the userform. What I posted is a 'proof of concept', not a complete solution - especially as you haven't supplied anywhere enough detail for that.

Comment: I did try it, including with a userform instead of a message box, but it won't let me run it modeless (which I forgot to mention in the question before) without running all the way through to the last instance. The code works great for what it does, but I was after a way to find the next instance after the current selection and doesn't require for it to be run all the way through. My code is currently around 2000 lines over half of which is runs on the found word, so I had to simplfy it a lot to be able to post it but it is a lot simpler for my code to run this section inside the userform.

Comment: @Kagekiba There is nothing about the concept behind the code I posted that prevents its use in a modeless userform; you just need to design the userform appropriately and replace the input box & message box references in the code I posted with the relevant userform control references.