# Selection.Find within a range

Tags: vba, ms-word, range

I am not familiar with Word VBA and am having a problem with Selection.Find.

I want to replace commas by decimal points in a range of cells in a table. However I can only get Selection.Find to replace either all commas in the document or only the first comma in the range.

What I would like is something like Selection.Replace What:=".", Replacement:="," in Excel, but Word does not support that.

Suggestions very gratefully received!

CJ

```
Sub Replace_Percent_Separator()
'Correct percent separator in row 6, table 2

Dim PcentCells As Range

Path = "C:\xxx\Word\"
file = Dir(Path & "*.docx")

Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Do While file <> ""

    Documents.Open Filename:=Path & file

    With ActiveDocument

        Set PcentCells = .Range(Start:=.Tables(2).Cell(6, 2).Range.Start, _
            End:=.Tables(2).Cell(6, 10).Range.End)
        PcentCells.Select

        With Selection.Find
            .Text = ","
            .Replacement.Text = "."
            .Forward = True
            .Wrap = wdFindContinue
            .Format = False
            .MatchCase = False
            .MatchWholeWord = False
            .MatchWildcards = False
            .MatchSoundsLike = False
            .MatchAllWordForms = False
            .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll '<-- replaces throughout document
            '.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceOne '<-- replaces in first cell but no other cells
        End With

    End With

    ActiveDocument.Save

    ActiveDocument.Close

    file = Dir()

Loop

Application.DisplayAlerts = True
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: See if the explanation in this answer helps:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51925805/vba-how-to-start-a-selection-halfway-through-the-text-in-a-table/51932924#51932924

Comment: Possible duplicate of [VBA - How to start a selection halfway through the text in a table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51925805/vba-how-to-start-a-selection-halfway-through-the-text-in-a-table)

Comment: Thanks! I have gone with Macropod's `.Wrap = wdFindStop` solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given your problem description, your code can be reduced to:

```
Sub Replace_Percent_Separator()
'Correct percent separator in row 6, table 2
file = Dir("C:\xxx\Word\*.docx")

Do While file <> ""
  Documents.Open FileName:=Path & file, AddToRecentFiles:=False, Visible:=False
  With ActiveDocument
    With .Tables(2).Row(6).Range.Find
      .Text = ","
      .Replacement.Text = "."
      .Forward = True
      .Wrap = wdFindStop
      .Format = False
      .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
    End With
    .Close SaveChanges:=True
  End With
  file = Dir()
Loop

End Sub
```

As can be seen, there is no need to select anything and, by using wdFindStop instead of wdFindContinue, the Find/Replace stops where it should.

Comment: Thanks Macropod! `.Wrap = wdFindStop` was the silver bullet and it has saved me hours googling up the wrong tree! Also more concise code! Many thanks!