# Word Macro To Delete Pages With Specific Text

Tags: string, vba, ms-word, find, selection

I'm trying to delete any page that contains a specific text such as the sentence below (strSearch =). But I get a 5904 Error when I try running my macro... Any clue?

```
  Sub DeletePages()
    Dim strSearch As String
    Dim rgeStart As Range
    Set rgeStart = Selection.Range

    strSearch = "Report the content of the ""StatusBar"" status bar message to the results."

    With ActiveDocument.Range.Find
      .Text = strSearch
      Do While .Execute
        With .Parent
          .Select With Selection
          .Bookmarks("\Page").Range.Delete
        End With
      End With
    Loop
  End With

  rgeStart.Select
  Application.Browser.Target = wdBrowsePage
End Sub
```

Comment: Proper formatting helps identify problems...

Comment: Which line of code triggers the error? What' the error message? Have you tried stepping through the code to make sure it's doing what you expect? The entire Find section isn't making much sense to me, but you don't provide any comments so it's not clear what you expect it to be doing...

Answer (score 0):

I get a syntax error on .Select With Selection, and there is no intellisense with this line...it seems that objects are not able to access properties and methods because with statements are embedded in one another.

The following worked for me...I had to delete the last page differently

```
 Sub DeletePages()
'source1 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13465709/repeating-microsoft-word-vba-until-no-search-results-found
'source2 https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb208876(v=office.12).aspx

    Dim strSearch As String

    strSearch = "GoodBye"

    With Selection.Find
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindStop
        .Text = strSearch
        .Execute
    End With


    Do While Selection.Find.Found = True And iCount < 1000
        iCount = iCount + 1
        Selection.HomeKey Unit:=wdStory
        Selection.Find.Execute
        If Selection.Find.Found Then
            'Get Current page
            CurPage = Selection.Information(wdActiveEndAdjustedPageNumber)

            'Check if current page is the last page
            If CurPage = FindLastPage Then
                ActiveDocument.Range(Selection.Start, ActiveDocument.Range.End).Delete
            Else
                ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("\Page").Range.Delete
            End If
        End If
    Loop

End Sub
Function FindLastPage()
    'Source https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/293861
    'Iterate each section in the document to retrieve the end page of the
    'document and compute the page count in that section. The results are
    'displayed in the Immediate window.
    Dim oSec As Object
    Dim nStartPg As Integer, nEndPg As Integer, nSecPages As Integer
    Dim NumSections As Integer
    NumSections = ActiveDocument.Sections.Count
    nStartPg = 1
    For Each oSec In ActiveDocument.Sections
       nEndPg = oSec.Range.Information(3) - 1  'wdActiveEndPageNumber=3
       'Account for the last page.
       If oSec.Index = NumSections Then nEndPg = nEndPg + 1
       nSecPages = nEndPg - nStartPg + 1
       FindLastPage = nSecPages
    Next

End Function
```

Comment: Sorry, the comment timed out while I was trying to get the phrasing right... <sigh>
I don't understand why you need the function FindLastPage as whether you delete or not doesn't seem to depend on the section? Why don't you use ActiveDocument.ComputeStatistics(wdStatisticPages)?

I don't understand why you're using AND iCount < 1000?

Comment: Nitpicking: 1) The comment in FindLastPage is inaccurate: the code does not contain any Debug.Print statements. 2) You should be passing a Document object to FindLastPage to be sure it's working on the same document as the calling procedure. 3) Assigning nSecPages to FindLastPage should follow the Next statement: no need to assign the value in every loop.